# Conversion from Component to Behavior

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to convert a component to a behavior so I can disable and enable it at my pleasure. I have done this dozens of times but now I seem to be getting an error.

Code:

```
UnityEngine.Component book001RenderOld = GameObject.Find("Book001").GetComponent("MeshRenderer");
UnityEngine.Behaviour book001Render = (UnityEngine.Behaviour)book001RenderOld;
```

Error:

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast from a Component to Behaviour because Behaviour inherits from Component, not the other way around.
Most of the components have enabled property, Renderer included;

You can probably use:

```
GameObject.Find("Book001").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
//or
GameObject.Find("Book001").renderer = false;
```

but i recommend using a reference from the inspector instead of GameObject.Find();
just declare a public GameObject variable in your class and it will show in inspector so you can reference a GameObject to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UnityEngine.Behaviour book001Render = GameObject.Find("Book001").GetComponent("MeshRenderer") as Behaviour;
```

Then you could control the behaviour

```
book001Render.enabled = true;
```

Comment: That gets rid of that error but instead says Object reference not set to an instance of the object. I have seen this error before but don't know how to get rid of it @IsabelHM

Comment: I need to see more code from your class. This is the solution to your question and you are just having more than one error in your code. Happy holiday.